# Object literal as function argument with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

I have following script. from that i need to call the function which is inside the parameter object. lets say "`onOpen`"  is it possible? i tried to call it from "**`callIt`**" but it is not working so how i can do it.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Object With Arguments</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body onload="callIt()">

<script type="text/javascript">


$.fn.myPlugin = function (settings) {
    var options = jQuery.extend({
        name: "MyPlugin",
        target: document,
        onOpen: function () {
            document.write('on open');
        },
        onClose: function () {},
        onSelect: function () {}
    }, settings);
    document.write(options.name + '<br/>')
}


function callIt(){

    $.fn.myPlugin.options.onOpen();

}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `onOpen` is a property of the `options` object, which is a local variable. It can be overwritten by passing a new function to the settings, but you can't call it from outside the plugin.

Comment: Oppppps.... got it. thanks for early comment. you means i can overwrite/implement when it call ?

Comment: @user3251472: Yes. You're supposed to pass `settings`. Look at [how `$.extend` works](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.extend/)